# Upload local repository to Bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

How can I upload my code from my local machine to Bitbucket using Tortoise Hg? Can somebody provide step-by-step procedure? I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read Bitbucket's documentation?

They have an extensive ["Bitbucket 101" tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Bitbucket+101) which explains all the basics step by step.

Quotes from the link:

> If you are new to hosting your code, code management with distributed
>   version control systems (DVCS), or either Git or Mercurial, this
>   Bitbucket 101 tutorial gives you a taste all of them. In this
>   tutorial, you'll first install both Git and Mercurial for your
>   operating system. You'll do some work using both Git and then
>   Mercurial. Throughout, you'll use the hosted code management system
>   that is Bitbucket.
>
> [...]
>
> **How to work through the tutorial**
>
> If you are totally new to DVCS and/or Bitbucket, you should work
>   through each page sequentially as each new page builds on the material
>   from the previous pages  At the end of each page is a Next heading
>   that navigates to the consequent page. If you get lost you can use the
>   navigation bar (to your left) to locate the next page. If you feel
>   confident skipping pages or just going to the pages you need, feel
>   free to do that too.
>   If you are a total beginner you should allow at
>   least a couple of hours to work through the entire tutorial. If you
>   are experienced or just skimming pages, much of this will be familiar
>   to you and it should not take too long.